# Input function Name error

Tags: python

```
input_test = input("enter somethings eaten in the last 24 hrs:")
print(input_test)

enter somethings eaten in the last 24 hrs:seafood, dairy, nuts, chocolatecake

NameErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-7bc4fc2d8475> in <module>()
----> 1 input_test = input("enter somethings eaten in the last 24 hrs:")
      2 print(input_test)

/home/nbuser/anaconda2_501/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ipykernel/ipkernel.pyc in <lambda>(prompt)
    174             self._sys_eval_input = builtin_mod.input
    175             builtin_mod.raw_input = self.raw_input
--> 176             builtin_mod.input = lambda prompt='': eval(self.raw_input(prompt))
    177         self._save_getpass = getpass.getpass
    178         getpass.getpass = self.getpass

/home/nbuser/anaconda2_501/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ipykernel/ipkernel.pyc in <module>()

NameError: name 'seafood' is not defined
```

Comment: I need help understanding why I am having this error

Comment: This is a py2 vs py3 error. Use `raw_input`.

Comment: @user2285236 argh -- I was too slow with the dupe ;)